# iTextSharp not displaying Arabic Text Plus number

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I Use Itextsharp library to print Arabic text in PDf. I have following code to print Arabic Text plus number but it doesn't display.

```
string fontLoc = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "TIMES.ttf");
BaseFont bf2 = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontLoc, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf2, 10);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("24 البطاقة", f), 123, 214, 0, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL, ColumnText.AR_LIG);
```

where as if the text contains only Arabic I am able to display.Any one have idea how to do this ?

Comment: Which version you are using of Itextsharp?

Comment: version : 5.5.13.0

Comment: Does your "TIMES.ttf" contain Arabic glyphs?